# Bash alias and bash function with several arguments

Tags: bash

I want to use both bash alias and bash function with several arguments. I emulate svn sub commands.

```
$ svngrep -nr 'Foo' .
$ svn grep -nr 'Foo' .
```

My expectation is both act as below:

```
grep --exclude='*.svn-*' --exclude='entries' -nr 'Foo' .
```

But actual, only alias ('svngrep') does well, function ('svn grep') causes invalid option error. How to write my .bashrc?

```
#~/.bashrc

alias svngrep="grep --exclude='*.svn-*' --exclude='entries'"

svn() {
  if [[ $1 == grep ]]
then
  local remains=$(echo $@ | sed -e 's/grep//')
  command "$svngrep $remains"
else
  command svn "$@"
fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `shift` to remove the first word from the positional parameters: this preserves the array-like nature of `"$@"`.

```
svn() {
  if [[ $1 = grep ]]; then
    shift
    svngrep "$@"
  else
    command svn "$@"
  fi
}
```

With bash's `[[` builtin, single `=` is used for string equality and double `==` is used for pattern matching -- you only need the former in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`svngrep` is not a variable. It's an alias used by bash. Therefore have to create a new variable like:

```
svngrep_var="grep --exclude='*.svn-*' --exclude='entries'"
```

And use it in your snippet:

```
...
command "$svngrep_var $remains"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-factor this by myself. And work fine! Thanks!

```
#~/.bashrc
alias svngrep="svn grep"
svn() {
if [[ $1 == grep ]]
then
    local remains=$(echo $* | sed -e 's/grep//')
    command grep --exclude='*.svn-*' --exclude='entries' $remains
else
  command svn $*
fi
}
```

I choice I keep alias simple. And I use $* instead of $@.

Edited: 2012-06-11

```
#~/.bashrc
alias svngrep="svn grep"
svn() {
  if [[ $1 = grep ]]
  then
    shift
    command grep --exclude='*.svn-*' --exclude='entries' "$@"
  else
    command svn "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and [Special Parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Special_Parameters).

Comment: This will be very fragile; please read Dennis's links and then use @glenn's solution instead.

Comment: Thanks, I understand deferences between $* and $@. And I must use doublequated $@, like "$@".